# Conflict: onlyamsmath and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, incompatibility

To force myself and collaborators to only use AMS-Math commands, I load this package in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}
```

However, when this is combined with `TikZ`, I get into trouble when using TikZ's calc library, as this involves using `$` for computations. How can I resolve this conflict?

MWE: Try uncommenting `onlyamsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}                       
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (node1)   []                  {Box 2 text};
\node (node2)   [right=of node1]    {Box 3 text};

\draw[->] (node2.north)  --  ++(0,0.5)  -| ($ (node1.east) + (0.25,0) $);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TikZ 3.0.0 has a `babel` library intended for compatibility with the `babel` package, that fixes catcodes within `tikzpicture`, and seems to also solve the `onlyamsmath` compatibility issue for me.

Note: as cfr points out, this does of course still disable `onlyamsmath` checking within TikZ pictures

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {inline equation: $a^b$} -- 
        (4,0) coordinate (B) node[below, text width=3cm] {
          Checking does still occur within nodes, so this produces a warning:
          $$a^b$$
        } --  
        ($ (A)!0.5!(B)!sin(60)*2!90:(B) $) node[above] {calculated point} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

From the TikZ manual:

> 12.2.3 Handling Catcodes and the Babel Package
>
> Inside a TikZ picture, most symbols need to have the category code 12 (normal text) in order to ensure that the parser works properly. This is typically not the case when packages like babel are used, which change catcodes aggressively.
>
> To solve this problem, Tik Z provides a small library also called babel (which can, however, also be used together with any other package that globally changes category codes). What it does is to reset the category codes at the beginning of every {tikzpicture} and to restore them at the beginning of every node. In almost all cases, this is exactly would you would expect and need, so I recommend to always load this library by saying \usetikzlibrary{babel}. For details on what, exactly, happens with the category codes, see Section 43.

Comment: Welcome! This is a neat use of the library ;). You should probably point out that this will disable checking within TikZ pictures, though.

Comment: Added a note to that effect, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Can't upvote again :(.

Comment: Actually, taking another look... TikZ babel does make sure to restore catcodes within nodes, so I think checking does still happen there... is there anywhere else within a tikzpicture where checking would be important?

Comment: Hmm... Good point. I guess this would cover labels, edge nodes and edge labels? I guess even in a `pic`, maths would have to be in a node inside the `pic`? So maybe this really would work as well as - or better than? - [Loop Space's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78758/)?

Comment: I would think so, if we assume TikZ uses nodes to underly anything that contains text. I'm still fairly new to TikZ though, so I can't be 100% sure. At the very least, works for basic node usage for me in a local test.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with the `quotes` library: I don't get warnings with `$$` in that case. It does seem to work with regular labels and nodes on edges if quotes aren't used, though.

Comment: Is @cfr comment still relevant as of 2022?

Answer (score 13):

The two packages are indeed incompatible, as **onlyamsmath** changes `$` into an active character in order to check whether `$$...$$` is used.

This conflicts heavily with the workings of **tikz**. However, the things checked by the package are

```
eqnarray
eqnarray*
displaymath
$$
```

so it doesn't seem to be really necessary. However, the following code

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\tikzpicture{\catcode`$=3 }
\preto\tikz{\catcode`$=3 }
```

inserted after loading TiKZ may solve the incompatibility.

Answer (score 13):

You could adjust the catcode of the `$` within the `tikzpicture` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\let\@@tikzpicture\tikzpicture
\def\tikzpicture{\catcode`\$=3 \@@tikzpicture}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red,ultra thick] (0,0) -- ($(2,0)+(2,2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have tested this solution (as well as @egreg's) with your MWE and both solutions seem to work fine.

Answer (score 5):

The solutions from Peter Grill and egreg and jofel involve turning off `onlyamsmath`s checking in either a `tikzpicture` (Peter Grill and egreg) environment or the whole document (jofel).  However, *assuming* that one wants to use the full capability of `onlyamsmath` in the entire document, none of these solutions is quite right.

The problem is that `onlyamsmath` changes the catcode of `$` at `\begin{document}`.  So when TikZ is loaded it doesn't know that `$` will change its catcode later and so merrily sets up stuff matching `$` with its *current* catcode, namely 3.

Now, because TikZ relies a lot on special symbols (`;` is only the start of it), it *generally* is quite robust against catcode changes.  If you look at the source of `tikz.code.tex` you'll see a lot of `` \ifnum\catcode`\;=\active `` and similar (*robust* but not *steadfast*: it only checks for a change between whatever-was-in-use-at-load-time and active).  It doesn't do this for `$`, though.  Perhaps it should.  One possibility would be to add the necessary checks.  This wouldn't be hard since, despite egreg's assertion, `$`s are not *heavily* used in TikZ so there would only need to be a few changes made.  However, a quicker alternative is to ensure that the right catcode is in place when TikZ is loaded.  This can be done with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\edef\dolcat{\the\catcode`\$}
\catcode`\$=13
\usepackage{tikz}                       
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\catcode`\$=\dolcat\relax

\usepackage[all,warning]{onlyamsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (node1)   []                  {Box 2 text};
\node (node2)   [right=of node1]    {Box 3 text};

\draw[->] (node2.north)  --  ++(0,0.5)  -| ($ (node1.east) + (0.25,0)
$);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which works with your MWE and also complains about `$$` in TikZ nodes.

(Whilst I agree with egreg about the necessity of `onlyamsmath` there are plenty of packages that mess with catcodes of symbols of significance and I think that adjusting TikZ - or faking it - to play nicely is the better route to take when conflicts arise.)

Comment: Nice answer; however `$` *is* heavily used in the `calc` library. :) My assumption was that people who use `$$...$$` in a TikZ node are on their own. :)

Comment: @egreg Depends on your definition of "heavily used".  I was looking at the code of the library.  There are three macros that have `$` in the parameter text (or body) which would need an alternative with `$` active.  There are three more in `tikz.code.tex`.  So fixing it in the code would not be hard.  That's what I meant by "heavily used".

Comment: @AndrewStacey if you provide a patch against the current TikZ version to accept active dollars in the calc lib, I would commit that to tikz CVS (please include suitable test cases).

Comment: This ... feature still bit me as of 2022. So did this fix get into tikz and is it the same as the `babel` library solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` protection from `onlyamsmath` makes lots of problems, not only with `tikz` (see e.g. this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59984/use-mathematical-equation-in-caption-with-onlyamsmath)).
To disable this incompatible feature, but not the other protections from `onlyamsmath`, add to your preamble *after* loading `onlyamsmath`.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\$=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, the 
`onlyamsmath` [manual](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/onlyamsmath/onlyamsmath.pdf) notes that the `nodollardollar` switch can be used to fix this specific problem, like this:

```
\usepackage[nodollardollar]{onlyamsmath}
```

However, the manual also notes that it "might have other side effects".