# Use mathematical equation in caption with onlyamsmath

Tags: hyperref, amsmath

Apparently it seems to raise a warning »LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.« if I want to use a mathematical equation in a figure's caption and I use the onlyamsmath and the hyperref packages in the document's preamble as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,error]{onlyamsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Reference~\ref{fig:foobar}.

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \caption{Foo Bar $f=2$}
  \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have currently no clue why this happens and what I should change ...

Comment: The warning is perfectly normal at the first run, because LaTeX doesn't yet know what number the label `fig:foobar` refers to. It will be issued every time LaTeX finds a new label or some reference has changed. A new run of LaTeX will fix the "problem".

Comment: For more complicated documents even three, four,... compilation runs can be necessary.

Comment: I think you may have found a bug.  The .aux file is unchanged from run 1 to run 2 of LaTeX, but the warning keeps coming up no matter how many times I run it.  Disabling either onlyamsmath or hyperref makes the problem go away, so I imagine the problem is a conflict between those two packages (both of which do some scary low-level stuff).

Comment: See my answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78757/10777 how to remove the `$` feature from amsmath which is the source of many problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right solution, in my opinion, is not using `onlyamsmath` at all: it makes more damages than it solves.

However, if you really prefer using it, then accustom yourself to write

```
\(a=b\)
```

for all formulas, instead of `$a=b$`. And remember to load also the `fixltx2e` package, otherwise formulas in captions will result in disasters when trying to use `\listoffigures` or `\listoftables`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}    
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,error]{onlyamsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Reference~\ref{fig:foobar}.

\begin{figure}[htb!]
  \caption{Foo Bar \(f=2\)}
  \label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is solved when you use the LaTeX inline math environment `\(` ... `\)` instead of the commonly used (though plain TeX directive) `$` ... `$`.

Comment: True, since the problem is in the catcode of $ (as I explained in my answer).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really solve the problem: look at the generated `.aux` file.

Comment: @egreg: Gee wizz - just as long as you don't create a contents for your floats.

Comment: @Werner This works fine, but how do you deal with a latex expression that involves braces, e.g., `\caption{ \( \lambda_{\boldmath k} \)}` produces an error

Comment: @LeoSimon: You're probably looking for `\caption{ \( \lambda_{\boldsymbol{k}} \)}` - some macros need `\protect`ion in order to survive being written to the `.lof`. In those cases use `\protect\<macro>`.

Answer (score 3):

The explanation is quite simple - but only once you know it;).  Actually, I've been able to run into a similar issue *without* `hyperref`, but I suspect the problem is the same.

When you run LaTeX on a source file, *first* the `aux` file is read and *after* that the `\AtBeginDocument` commands are executed.  And since `onlyamsmath` says

```
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode‘\$=13 }
```

it means that labels etc. are *read* under normal catcode regime of `$`, and *checked* during compilation with `$`'s catcode set to "active".  Therefore for all labels using this character LaTeX will *always* complain.  (And what makes the problem tricky is that the *character codes* of everything in the `aux` file stay the same, i.e. the `aux` file itself stays identical in the sense of `diff`.

The remedy to this problem is thus quite simple: just say

```
\catcode`\$=13
```

somewhere in your preamble (best right before **edit:** *not before, but after*, since `onlyamsmath` uses `$` with its normal catcode too! `\usepackage{onlyamsmath}`, or at least take care so that between this line and loading of that package you *never* actually *use* the dollar sign).